# como insertar datos en coleciones relacionadas en mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, relaciones, modelos

Tengo 2 modelos los cuáles tuve que relacionar, ya que un usuario puede tener una o mas empresas asociadas, así que tengo los 2 modelos definidos de la siguiente forma:

- modelo usuarios:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require( 'mongoose' ),
      Enterprice = require( './enterprice.model' );  


const userSchema = Schema(
  {
    enterprice: [{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Enterprice"
    }],
    role: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
      enum: ['enterpriceAdmin', 'applicantEnterprice', 'deliveryMan', 'admin' ]
    },
    run: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      // required: true
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
module.exports = model( 'User', userSchema );
```

- modelo empresas:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require( 'mongoose' );

const enterpriceSchema = Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    commune: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    province: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    region: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
module.exports = model( 'Enterprice', enterpriceSchema );
```

estoy relacionando ambos modelos con un atributo enterprise en el modelo user haciendo uso del objectId, hasta aquí creo que todo va bien.

Ahora, como sería la forma correcta de actualizar ambos modelos cuándo se ingresen datos? Supongamos que registro un usuario junto a su empresa. Primero registraría la empresa, y luego debo obtener el _id de esa empresa y "pushearlo" en el atributo del modelos users y posteriormente crear el usuario con estos datos? o como sería ? estoy comenzando apenas con Mongodb, y por mas que busco info, no encuentro algo donde expliquen casos como este.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose tiene varios métodos para insertar documentos en un array, unas de las maneras para poder realizar lo que deseas es utilizar el método `addToSet()` que simplemente agrega un documento al array PERO, solo lo agrega si el id es diferente, básicamente lo que hace es decirle a mongo, si este documento ya existe entonces no lo guardes, de lo contrario guárdalo

1. Creamos el usuario (utilizo async/await)

---

```
import UserModel from "./userModel.js"
import EnterpriceModel from "./enterpriceModel.js"

function CreateUserAndEnterprice(req, res){
    try{
      const new_user = new UserModel(req.body.user) //creamos el usuario con los datos que envia el cliente
      const new_enterprice = new EnterpriceModel(req.body.interprice) //creamos la empresa con los datos que envia el cliente
      new_user.interprice.addToSet(new_interprice._id) //se agrega el id de la empresa al campo enterprice del modelo de usuario
      await new_user.saver() //guardamos el usuario en la bd
      await new_interprice.saver() //guardamos la empresa en la bd
      return res.status(200).json({message: "success"}) //respondemos al cliente
    } catch(err){
      console.error(err) //mostramos el error por consola para poder solucionar futuros errores
      return res.status(500).send("error") //en caso de error respondemos al cliente con un 500
    }
}
```

de esta manera lo que estamos haciendo es crear el usuario y la empresa y posteriormente insertar el id de la empresa en el campo `enterprice` del modelo empresa, de esta manera cuando necesites pedir el usuario con la referencia podrías hacer esto

```
const usuario = await UserModel.findById(id).populate("enterprice")
```

esto retornara el usuario con los datos de las empresas asociadas en el campo `enterprice`.
por ultimo, te aconsejaría que los modelos los nombres con minúsculas para poder evitar problemas a la hora de referenciar documentos, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.!!

Comment: Veo que usas new, yo no estoy trabajando con clases, esto afectaría? Además, cuál sería la diferencia en hacer un save y no un creare? Yo para crear el documento usaba creare en vez de save.

Comment: cuando haces un `module.exports = model( 'Enterprice', enterpriceSchema )` estas exportando un constructor, los constructores comunmente se inician con un `new`, no importa de la manera como crees el documento lo importante es crear primero la empresa y luego el usuario y antes de guardarlo ingresar en el campo `enterprise` el id de la empresa

Comment: Me refería a la diferencia entre hacer un create y no un save.

Comment: Ok, no lo he podido probar aún. Pero tengo otra consulta si no es mucha molestia. Al hacer un create creo q inmediatamente lo guarda en la Base de datos, correcto? En cambio de la forma como lo explicas con el new, por lo que entiendo, solo se crea el documento más no se guarda en la base de datos hasta haces el save. Correcto?

Comment: es correcto, con un `create` activa el middleware `save()` automaticamente, puedes verlo [aqui](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create)

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. probaré con la respuesta. Yo intento aprender directamente desde la documentación pero no logro entender todo al 100%. Aún tengo muchísima dudas, y no he encontrado un curso o tutorial donde expliquen bien para un novato en mongo.